# Library to Connect to Mssql 2008 Express Edition with PHP

Tags: php, windows, sql-server-2008, odbc

Which is better to use?

- `mssql_connect`
- `odbc_connect`
- or `PDO` for odbc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use PDO, and make a habit out of it.

Why?

PDO is a modern and very mature interface which actually makes it fun and easy to make prepared statements. Another reason is, as stated on [their manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php):

> PDO provides a data-access abstraction layer, which means that, regardless of which database you're using, you use the same functions to issue queries and fetch data. PDO does not provide a database abstraction; it doesn't rewrite SQL or emulate missing features. You should use a full-blown abstraction layer if you need that facility.

Did i say it was easy?